# Finding text between font sizes in Word VBA

Tags: vba, ms-word

I'm looking to find text between font sizes in Word VBA. I'm wondering if there's a better way than my code below.

It looks for the minimum font size and then iterates, incrementing by .5 until the maximum. As far as I can tell, there's no way to search for a font size range.

There's a bit of extra matching that you can ignore (it's part of a semantic-less footnote reference matching script)

```
Dim findResults As Scripting.Dictionary
Set findResults = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

Set contentRange = ActiveDocument.Content

' Find fonts between range

Dim min
min = 6

Dim max
max = 8

Dim currentFontSize
currentFontSize = min

Do While max >= currentFontSize

    Selection.HomeKey Unit:=wdStory
    Set contentRange = ActiveDocument.Content

    With contentRange.Find.Font
        .Size = currentFontSize
    End With

    With contentRange.Find.Font.Shading
        .ForegroundPatternColor = wdColorAutomatic
    End With

    With contentRange.Find
        .Text = "[0-9]{1,3}"
        .MatchWildcards = True
        .Wrap = wdFindStop
    End With

    contentRange.Find.Execute

    While contentRange.Find.Found
        If contentRange.Font.Position > 2 Then
            Set myRange = ActiveDocument.Range(start:=contentRange.start - 10, End:=contentRange.start + Len(contentRange.Text))
            findResults.Add contentRange.Text, Trim(Replace(myRange.Text, vbCr, ""))
        End If
        'Selection.MoveRight Unit:=wdCharacter, Count:=Len(contentRange.Text)
        contentRange.Collapse wdCollapseEnd
        contentRange.Find.Execute
    Wend

    currentFontSize = currentFontSize + 0.5

Loop
```

Answer (score 0):

My approach would be to find all instances of the text, then test the font size within the loop. That way, you need only do two font size tests - .Font.Size > 5.5 and .Font.Size < 8.5. Try something based on:

```
Dim FindResults As Scripting.Dictionary, Rng As Range
Set FindResults = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
With ActiveDocument.Range
  With .Find
    .ClearFormatting
    .Replacement.ClearFormatting
    .Text = "[0-9]{1,3}"
    .Font.Shading.ForegroundPatternColor = wdColorAutomatic
    .Forward = True
    .MatchWildcards = True
    .Wrap = wdFindStop
    .Execute
  End With
  Do While .Find.Found = True
    If .Font.Size > 5.5 Then
      If .Font.Size < 9.5 Then
        If .Font.Position > 2 Then
          Set Rng = .Duplicate
          Rng.Start = Rng.Start - 10
          FindResults.Add .Text, Trim(Replace(Rng.Text, vbCr, ""))
        End If
      End If
    End If
    .Collapse wdCollapseEnd
    .Find.Execute
  Loop
End With
```

Comment: I'd wondered about whether it would be faster to do several searches for font sizes, or search and then filter. Which way do you think is fastest for a document with potentially hundreds or thousands of numbers?

Comment: That really depends on the relative frequency of numbers formatted within your font range compared to those formatted outside it. Only testing will tell. You might also want to consider the way the data are sorted in the output: your code sorts them in order by font size; mine sorts them in order regardless of font size.